# HTML & Bootstrap nav-right doesn't align elements to the right?

Tags: html

I'm working on a navbar/header using Twitter bootstrap, and my elements aren't aligning to the right. 
This is one of the many methods I've tried:

```
<div class="nav navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                    <form method="post" action="register.php" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning navbar-right">Register</button>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

but to no avail. How can I achieve this goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/gitagatoko/1/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">       
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
            <form method="post" action="register.php" class="">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Register</button>
             </form>
             <form method="post" action="index.php" class="">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
             </form>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

BTW, your markup was a little bit wrong, because you put your `<form>` tag's into `<ul></ul>` tags

without `<li></li>` tags.

Comment: doesn't seem to work... everything is still aligned left instead of right.

Comment: The first demo was working if you resize your browser, however, I updated my answer. Look at demo 1

Comment: still doesn't pull my button(s) to the right, infact I have two buttons stacked now. Similar to this, however the buttons are on the left: http://jsbin.com/wumimejade/edit?html,css,output